# why dont my columns resize when the browser size changes

Tags: html, css

I have 4 images in 4 columns in a grid and i want them to resize according to the browser size. The 4 images have a blur filter on hover with text on hover. The Wo,we,wa, & pool classes are the individual images that are in columns.

I haven't tried much because i dont know where the problem starts, im still sort of new to CSS

```
<div class="images">
<div class="pool">
<h2> Here </h2>
<img src="img/cpu.jpg">
</div>

<div class="we">
<h2> Here </h2>
<img src="img/cubes.jpg">
</div>

<div class="wo">
<h2> Here </h2>
<img src="img/preme.jpg">
</div>

<div class="wa">
<h2> Here </h2>
<img src="img/hand.jpg">
</div>
</div>


.images {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
padding: 2rem 3.5rem;
grid-gap: 10px;
position: relative;




}
.images img{
height:9rem;
width:15rem;
padding: 5px;
transition: .3s;

}



.images h2 {
position: absolute;
padding-left: 5.5rem;
padding-top: 3.5rem;
color: white;
justify-content: center;
transition: .3s;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 1;
height: 6rem;
width: 9rem;
margin: .1rem .22rem;



}

.images h2:hover {
opacity: 1;
}


.pool {
grid-column: 1;

}

.we {
grid-column: 2;
}

.wa {
grid-column: 4;

}

.wo {
grid-column: 3;
}




.pool:hover img {
filter:blur(5px) brightness(60%);

}

.wa:hover img {
filter:blur(5px);

}



.we:hover img {
filter:blur(5px);

}

enter code here

.wo:hover img {
filter:blur(5px);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your .images img to my css

```
.images img{
height:100%;
width:100%;
padding: 5px;
transition: .3s;

}
```

you can try the code here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wLGrom Hopes this answers your question.

Set the % to what you want.